# Class 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http' not found in Laravel 7.x

Tags: laravel, httprequest

In my Laravel app and as a scheduled task, I want to make an Http request in my custom class but I get

```
Class 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http' not found {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Class 'Illuminate\\Support\\Facades\\Http' not found
```

Here is my custom class

```
<?php

namespace App\MyModels\GetData;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class Test
{
    public function __invoke()
    {
        Log::info("Cron executed : ");
        $response = Http::get("https://google.com");
        Log::info(print_r($response, true));
    }
}
```

in Laravel documentation, it says :

> To make requests, you may use the get, post, put, patch, and delete methods. First, let's examine how to make a basic GET request:
>
> use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;
>
> $response = Http::get('http://test.com');

Comment: `Http` is not a Facade that I'm aware of. What documentation are you referencing on its usage?

Comment: @TimLewis here https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/http-client. I just added its explanation to my question

Comment: Ah, so it is `GuzzleHttp`; cool. I'm familiar with that. Did you run the composer command? `composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle`

Comment: @TimLewis yes I did!

Comment: Ok, next step; run `composer dump-autoload`, just in case that didn't get updated. Following that, try again, and if that doesn't work, then do `php artisan tinker`, followed by `$http = new Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http();`; it should output something. Let me know when you've tried that.

Comment: @TimLewis PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Illuminate/Support/Facades/Http' not found in Psy Shell code on line 1

Comment: Still can't find it eh? Check your `vendor` folder; in terminal `cd vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades` and see if `Http.php` is found in there. (`ls -lah`)

Comment: @TimLewis there is no Http.php in that directory!

Comment: That's super bizarre... Looks like a deficiency in the Laravel documentation. I notice that my local project has `guzzle` installed (`vendor/guzzlehttp`), but there's no Facade for it (note, I'm on 6.x, not 7x). I'm not sure if there's an extra step missing or something, but you definitely found an issue. Might be worth checking out the issues on the Framework GitHub: https://github.com/laravel/framework (might need to submit the issue elsewhere)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me, the issue had to do with the fact that (while I thought the project was on version 7 for Laravel) I appeared to be on version 6.x for Laravel. Updated to the newest version solved this issue for me. [Link to the GitHub issue that resolved my issue](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/33270)

Although the question is specific about version 7 I still feel this might help some people

Answer (score 1):

Based on comments you probably have a non-generic/minimal Laravel version installed.

1. Back up your current `composer.json` (from project root)
2. Open `composer.json`
3. Go to `require` property
4. Replace all `laravel/*` properties with default ones:

```
"laravel/framework": "^7.0",
"laravel/tinker": "^2.0"
```

5. Save the file and run `composer update && php artisan config:cache`

After that all facades should be installed correctly :)

---

For further reference if you want to create a new Laravel application, don't bother choosing a custom distribution (which may not contain all features as in OP's case). Use the default repository:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel MyLaravelProject
```

Answer (score 1):

Try importing the Http in your controller as shown below.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;
```

Hope that solves your issue.

Comment: the intention was good

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
use Hash;
```

instead of

```
use Illuminate\support\Facades\Hash;
```