# Class 'Illuminate\Support\facades\Http' not found

Tags: php, linux, laravel, apache, http

My Laravel app was running successfully locally on my PC using WAMP server

```
PHP 7.4.0
Laravel 7.20.0
WAMP 3.2.0
```

When I deployed my app on a RedHat server,

```
PHP 7.4.9
Laravel 7.20.0
Appache 2.4.6
RedHat 7
```

I faced the below error when I make an HTTP request:

```
Error: Class 'Illuminate\Support\facades\Http' not found in file /var/www/html/chatbot/app/Http/Controllers/BotController.php on line 25
```

The only difference is the `PHP version`

composer.json

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.2.5",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.2",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^1.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
        "laravel/framework": "^7.0",
        "laravel/helpers": "^1.2",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
        "laravel/ui": "^2.0",
        "yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "^9.10"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
        "facade/ignition": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.3.1",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^4.1",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.5"
    },
    "autoload": {
        .
        .
```

And please note that locally, i upgraded my laravel version from laravel 5 to laravel 7 from the beginning.

Do i have to install anything else on the server to make an HTTP request ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62458653/class-illuminate-support-facades-http-not-found-in-laravel-7-x please check this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Class 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http' not found in Laravel 7.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62458653/class-illuminate-support-facades-http-not-found-in-laravel-7-x)

Comment: @KamleshPaul php artisan serve: Laravel Framework 7.20.0 , But i was using an old version, and i upgraded it to 7.20.0

Comment: "Error: Class 'Illuminate\Support\facades\Http"  could be case issue. Try with capital F. as in `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http` in your BotController

Comment: @user3532758 yesss it is case sensitive!! it works now, thank youuuuu! but how locally its not case sensitive? if you want answer the question to put it right for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `Illuminate\Support\facades\Http` => `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http` . The `f` in facade needs to be in uppercase.

File names in Linux are case sensitive while in Windows/NTFS file systems, it's not. So, locally, it would not be a problem since your environment is Windows (assumed from WAMP).