# 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http' not found in laravel 5.8

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, api

I am trying to connect the zoom api in my projects I install the both of these ( `$ composer require firebase/php-jwt` OR
`$ composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle`) then i create traits and also create a controller and trying to create the zoom meeting by using laravel api.php routes but i face the errror

> "Class 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http' not found".

These version are install in my project :-

```
 "laravel/framework": "5.8.*",
  "php": "^7.1.3",
  "firebase/php-jwt": "^6.4",
  "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.5",
  "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
```

I need a zoom meeting link which zoom response api provide for the user after create the meeting .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Class 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http' not found in Laravel 7.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62458653/class-illuminate-support-facades-http-not-found-in-laravel-7-x)

Answer (score 2):

You are on Laravel version `5.8`, if you check [the Facades documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/facades#facade-class-reference) for that version, you will see that the `Http` facade was not a part of the framework at that time.

It is true that that facade requires `Guzzle`, which you installed, but this will not magically make the Facade appear in your Laravel project. The Laravel `Http` facade is essentially a wrapper around `Guzzle`, so you have two options here:

1. Use [the Guzzle package](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/), without using the facade;
2. Upgrade/migrate your project to a more recent version of Laravel (at least 7.x).

Laravel 5.8 was released 4 (!) years ago. I would highly suggest that you upgrade to a more recent version. If for whatever reason, this is not possible, you can always use the `Guzzle` package without the facade.

If you decide to upgrade, consulting [the upgrade guide](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/upgrade) for Laravel 6.0 would be a good start. Since you are on a very old version you will probably have to do all the updates sequentially. A tool like [Laravel Shift](https://laravelshift.com/) might help to simplify the process.

Answer (score 0):

http-client does not exist for this version of Laravel
it has introduced since laravel "7.x"